# Splitting MS Access query into multiple excel workbooks

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have got an existing query which is exported to excel through DoCmd.Transferspreadsheet.

In simple terms the query looks like below:

**Group | Client**

Group1  Client1

Group1  Client2

Group1  Client3

Group2  Client4

Group2  Client5

Group2  Client6

etc.

As some of the groups contain large number of clients, I am trying to find the code to help me split groups by pre-specified number of clients and export to excel, as follows:

Group1 - clients 1 to 300.xlsx

Group1 - clients 301 to 600.xlsx

Group2 - clients 1 to 300.xlsx

etc.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a query that includes clients 1-300 then export that query into excel.  You can even close out access and open excel for your users!

Here is my code for my DB... hopefully you can use it as well:

```
Private Sub Command14_Click()

DoCmd.OpenQuery "rtnbymonth_qry", acViewNormal, acEdit
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "rtnbymonth_Qry", acFormatXLS, "S:\Sales & Use Tax\2015\export.xls"
DoCmd.Close acQuery, "rtnbymonth_qry", acSaveNo

'Open Excel
Call OpenSpecific_xlFile
```

Comment: The problem is that on average I have circa 15,000 records in the query. I need it to be exported into individual spreadsheets of 300 records each.